# ArgoCD API Patch patch an application

Tags: argocd

I'm writing a web app that needs to patch an application in argocd using the API.  However I'm running into issue trying to do this operation. (even with curl I'm unable to get a 200)  I have various other operations working like create session and list all applications, but for some reason the PATCH application endpoint isn't working.

What I'm trying is the following:

```
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <token_from_create_session>" \
    --data '{"appNamespace": "default", "name": "argocd-seed-job", "patch": "{\"spec\":{\"source\":{\"targetRevision\":\"master\"}}}", "patchType": "merge", "project": "default"}' \
    -X PATCH \
    https://my_domain/api/v1/applications/argocd-seed-job
```

I get the following:

```
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

There isn't must info to go on this and was wondering if any have gotten the argocd PATCH operation working.  I'm trying to following the swagger document: https://cd.apps.argoproj.io/swagger-ui#operation/ApplicationService_Patch

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you